# Hay alguna manera de obtener el último parámetro insertado en la función CreateWindowEx?

Tags: c++, winapi

La idea es poder controlar una ventana desde una clase, y que cuando se ejecute
WinProc se puedan cambiar los datos de dicha clase, para determinar que hacer con una ventana en específico,por ejemplo cuando se dibuje una ventana.
También sirve hacer que se ejecute alguna función de dicha clase.

La clase para controlar la ventana sería como esta:

```
class FRAME
{
    vector<FRAME> Controls = *new vector<FRAME>();
public: 
    
    WNDDATA DATA; /* WNDDATA es una clase creada, para para que en un solo argumento se pasen todos los datos. */
    HWND Handler;
    

    FRAME(WNDCLASS& WC, WNDDATA data)
    {           
            DATA = data;
            Handler = CreateWindowEx(
                data.ShowStyle,                      
                WC.lpszClassName,            
                DATA.WindowName,    
                data.WindowStyle,           
                DATA.Bounds.left, DATA.Bounds.top, DATA.Bounds.right, DATA.Bounds.bottom,
                NULL,   NULL,   WC.hInstance,
                                
                this
            );                  
    }
    void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handler,DATA.ShowStyle);
        int size = Controls.size();
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        {
            Controls.at(c).Show();
        }
    }
    void AddControl(FRAME &F)
    { 

        SetParent(F.Handler, this->Handler);
        Controls.push_back(F);
    }
};
```

> EDICIÓN: Cabe aclarar, que todo debe ejecutarse en la función WindowProc (que procesa los mensajes de las ventanas), por lo que serviría cualquier cosa que permita obtener del HWND lo que se le añadió en el último parámetro que se le insertó a la funcion CreateWindowEx
> cuando se creaba dicho HWND. espero que se entienda.